# How to correctly differentiate between stem characters and literal characters while parsing in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am fairly new to Haskell and I'm trying to make a simple Parser and I'm using the Parsec module. The grammar for my parser is:

```
data Frag
  = Lt String
  | St
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Template = [Frag]

type FileT = Template
type CommandT = Template

data Rule
  = Rule [FileT] [FileT] [CommandT]
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Makefile = [Rule]
```

I have implemented all the way down to fragments (which would be sets of characters). Here is a snipped of how I'm trying to handle literal characters , i don't know how to handle Stem characters though:

```
template :: Parser [Frag]
template = 
    do result <- many frag
       return result
frag :: Parser Frag
frag = do Lt x <- (many (noneOf ['\n','\t','\r',':','.']))
          return x
```

But I'm getting this error I don't know why:

```
Parser\Impl.hs:72:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Frag’
    • In the pattern: Lt x
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        Lt x <- (many (noneOf ['\n', '\t', '\r', ':', ....]))
      In the expression:
        do { Lt x <- (many (noneOf ['\n', '\t', ....]));
             return x }

Parser\Impl.hs:73:11: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Frag’
      Expected type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                       String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Frag
        Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                       String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity String
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: return x
      In the expression:
        do { Lt x <- (many (noneOf ['\n', '\t', ....]));
             return x }
      In an equation for ‘frag’:
          frag
            = do { Lt x <- (many (noneOf ['\n', ....]));
                   return x }
```

Input :

```
"aaa : bbb ccc"
"\:aaa : \%bbb \\ccc
```

Output :

```
[["aaa"] , ["bbb"] , ["ccc"]]
[[":aaa"] , ["%bbb"] , ["\ccc"]]
```

Comment: What are stem characters? What is the grammar you are trying to parse? It would probably be very helpful if you provided an example input and the output you are trying to get for that example.

Comment: Done. Characters such as % : \ \n \t \r are excluded but if the string contains an '\' it makes it literal (eg " \%" -> "%" whereas "%" -> "") .

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> frag :: Parser Frag
> frag = do Lt x <- (many (noneOf ['\n','\t','\r',':','.']))
>           return x
> ```

`many`, here, produces a `Parser [Char]`. You are trying to match a `[Char]` result with a `Frag` pattern, resulting in a type error. Rather, you want...

```
frag :: Parser Frag
frag = do x <- (many (noneOf ['\n','\t','\r',':','.']))
          return (Lt x)
```

... or simply:

```
frag :: Parser Frag
frag = fmap Lt (many (noneOf ['\n','\t','\r',':','.']))
```

P.S.: In your other definition...

```
template :: Parser [Frag]
template = 
    do result <- many frag
       return result
```

... binding `result` only for immediately using `return` on it is redundant. You can just write:

```
template :: Parser [Frag]
template = many frag
```

P.P.S.: As you have noticed (and perhaps as you had expected), `many frag` isn't enough for doing what you want. You will need to specify, in one way or another, how to delimit your fragments.

Comment: Thanks! It cleared the error... Now my program loops forever. I suspect that many ( noneOf ... Statement

Comment: @NándorZ.Papp More precisely, I belive the problem manifests itself when you try to use `many frag`. Rather than a loop, here it bails out with `"Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string."`, which makes sense. If you want to break down the input string in several parts, you need to specify some sort of delimiter or length limit in the `frag` parser.